# How to efficiently zip matrix elements with their row numbers in Python?

Tags: python, performance, zip

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array `A`:

```
2 7 6 
3 8 9
```

How can I do a kind of zip to get an array

```
(2,0) (7,0) (6,0)
(3,1) (8,1) (9,1)
```

So, elements in the matrix are zipped with the row number. What would be an efficient way to do it that performs well for a large matrix `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
arr = np.array([[2, 7, 6], [3, 8, 9]])

row, col = arr.shape
res = np.dstack([arr, np.broadcast_to(np.arange(row), (col, row)).T])
```

```py
assert np.array_equal(
    res,
    np.array(
        [
            [(2, 0), (7, 0), (6, 0)],
            [(3, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)],
        ]
    ),
)
```

### Performance Comparison

```py
import numpy as np
import time

def f1(arr):
    row, col = arr.shape
    return np.dstack([arr, np.broadcast_to(np.arange(row), (col, row)).T])

def f2(arr):
    values = [(x, i[0]) for i, x in np.ndenumerate(arr)]
    return np.array(values, dtype="i4, i4").reshape(arr.shape)

def benchmark(f, *args):
    start = time.process_time()
    f(*args)
    return time.process_time() - start

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rg = np.random.default_rng(1)
    a = rg.random((3000, 3000))
    print(benchmark(f1, a))
    print(benchmark(f2, a))
```

```
0.046875
3.5625
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy [ndenumerate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)

```
arr = np.array([[2, 7, 6], [3, 8, 9]])
values = [(x, i[0]) for i, x in np.ndenumerate(arr)]
print(values)
# [(2, 0), (7, 0), (6, 0), (3, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

Comment: I think OP wants this as an ndarray in the same shape as the original, which could be done with `np.array(values, dtype='i4, i4').reshape(arr.shape)`.